# Switching between multiple databases in Rails without breaking transactions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, transactions

I am setting up a Rails app with multiple databases. It uses `ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection db_config` to switch between the databases (all of which are configured in database.yml).

`establish_connection` apparently breaks pending transactions on each call. One negative consequence is testing, where  `use_transactional_tests` must be disabled (leading to undesirably slow tests).

So ... how can a Rails app maintain multiple transactions on different databases at the same time? (To clarify, I'm not looking for a fancy cross-database transaction. Just a way for the database client, ie the Rails app, to maintain multiple transactions simultaneously, one per database.)

The only solution I've seen is [putting `establish_connection` directly in the class definition](http://www.ostinelli.net/setting-multiple-databases-rails-definitive-guide/), but that assumes you have a database dedicated to specific classes. I am applying a user-based sharding strategy, where a single record type is distributed across multiple databases, so the database needs to be switched dynamically in code.

Comment: Generally there isn't a way of maintaining a transaction across multiple databases.  This isn't specific to any language, just a limitation of what most database engines can handle.

Comment: I'm not looking for a complex cross-database transaction though; just want to know how the DB client (ie Rails app) can hold independent transactions simultaneously.  establish_connection is like a global variable that keeps resetting transactions.

Comment: Use different users?

Comment: These are already different databases

Comment: MySQL can do `BEGIN; ... db1.tblA...; ...db2.tblB...; COMMIT;`.  (If that you mean by "database" as opposed to "server".  See also "XA".  Show us the SQL.

Comment: How to use that with ActiveRecord? The question isn't really about MySQL, it's about Rails' `establish_connection` which seems to be the only way to switch between databases, but also has the side effect of closing transactions.

Comment: TBH it sounds to me like your pain points are an indicator that you should probably be using a distributed database such as riak, not trolling, just an observation

Comment: @engineerdave Possibly true, but I don't like the chances of migrating a Rails app to a non-standard data store for AR either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a tricky problem, because of tight coupling inside `ActiveRecord`, but I've managed to create some proof of concept that works. Or at least it looks like it works.

**Some background**

`ActiveRecord` uses a `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionHandler` class that is responsible for storing connection pools per model. By default there is only one connection pool for all models, because usual Rails app is connected to one database.

After executing `establish_connection` for different database in particular model, new connection pool is created for that model. And also for all models that may inherit from it.

Before executing any query, `ActiveRecord` first retrieves connection pool for relevant model and then retrieves the connection from the pool.

Note that above explanation may not be 100% accurate, but it should be close.

**Solution**

So the idea is to replace the default connection handler with custom one that will return connection pool based on provided shard description.

This can be implemented in many different ways. I did it by creating the proxy object that is passing shard names as disguised `ActiveRecord` classes. Connection handler is expecting to get AR model and looks at `name` property and also at `superclass` to walk the hierarchy chain of model. I've implemented `DatabaseModel` class that is basically shard name, but it is behaving like AR model.

**Implementation**

Here is example implementation. I've used sqlite database for simplicity, you can just run this file without any setup. You can also take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ronin/4f1b38fcbfd7532e1add7e0c8b71c05b)

```
# Define some required dependencies
require "bundler/inline"
gemfile(false) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem "activerecord", "~> 4.2.8"
  gem "sqlite3"
end

require "active_record"

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

DatabaseModel = Struct.new(:name) do
  def superclass
    ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end

# Setup database connections and create databases if not present
connection_handler = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionHandler.new
resolver = ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionSpecification::Resolver.new({
  "users_shard_1" => { adapter: "sqlite3", database: "users_shard_1.sqlite3" },
  "users_shard_2" => { adapter: "sqlite3", database: "users_shard_2.sqlite3" }
})

databases = %w{users_shard_1 users_shard_2}
databases.each do |database|
  filename = "#{database}.sqlite3"

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection({
    adapter: "sqlite3",
    database: filename
  })

  spec = resolver.spec(database.to_sym)
  connection_handler.establish_connection(DatabaseModel.new(database), spec)

  next if File.exists?(filename)

  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 1) do
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
    end
  end
end

# Create custom connection handler
class ShardHandler
  def initialize(original_handler)
    @original_handler = original_handler
  end

  def use_database(name)
    @model= DatabaseModel.new(name)
  end

  def retrieve_connection_pool(klass)
    @original_handler.retrieve_connection_pool(@model)
  end

  def retrieve_connection(klass)
    pool = retrieve_connection_pool(klass)
    raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection pool for #{klass}" unless pool
    conn = pool.connection
    raise ConnectionNotEstablished, "No connection for #{klass} in connection pool" unless conn
    puts "Using database \"#{conn.instance_variable_get("@config")[:database]}\" (##{conn.object_id})"
    conn
  end
end

User.connection_handler = ShardHandler.new(connection_handler)

User.connection_handler.use_database("users_shard_1")
User.create(name: "John Doe", email: "john.doe@example.org")
puts User.count

User.connection_handler.use_database("users_shard_2")
User.create(name: "Jane Doe", email: "jane.doe@example.org")
puts User.count

User.connection_handler.use_database("users_shard_1")
puts User.count
```

I think this should give an idea how to implement production ready solution. I hope I didn't miss anything obvious here. I can suggest couple of different approaches:

1. Subclass `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::ConnectionHandler` and overwrite those methods responsible for retrieving connection pools
2. Create completely new class implementing the same api as `ConnectionHandler`
3. I guess it is also possible to just overwrite `retrieve_connection` method. I don't remember where it is defined, but I think it is in `ActiveRecord::Core`.

I think approaches 1 and 2 are the way to go and should cover all cases when working with databases.