# How to switch to specific database for specific model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multiple-databases, apartment-gem

I am using apartment gem where it has multi tenancy. I want to have a solution like whenever that particular model is called or any execution happen it should switch to that specific database.

model name = RakeLog

main db_name = ABC

another db_name = ABC_logs

right now what I have done is created a class method in model

```
class RakeLog < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.switch_to_log
    current = Apartment::Tenant.current
    Apartment::Tenant.switch!(current+'_logs')
  end
end
```

what I am doing now is calling this method everywhere when I need to switch to 'logs' db. I want something like whenever this model gets called it should switch to 'logs' db **automatically**. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This could help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43819672/4160532

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, I think you want to connect to another database `db_name ABC_logs` from model class, if yes then this will help you.

```
class RakeLog < ActiveRecord::Base

  establish_connection ABC_logs_DB

  def self.switch_to_log
    current = Apartment::Tenant.current
    Apartment::Tenant.switch!(current+'_logs')
  end
end
```

You can check the complete tutorial [here](https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/)